# Setting user default directories

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, default

I have changed the `.config/user-dirs.dirs` file then I restarted computer but nothing has changed - what else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid changing this file directly, instead, you should use [`xdg-user-dirs-update`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xdg-user-dirs-update.1).

For example, to update the download directory, use:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD $HOME/PATH/TO/downloads
```

Make sure you changed `$HOME/PATH/TO/downloads` to your downloads directory.

`xdg-user-dirs-update`, **Resetting your configuration at each session start up.**
Consequently, you need to set `enabled=False` in your `user-dirs.conf` file instead of `enabled=True`. 
This file location is: `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` or `~/.config/user-dirs.conf`.
Done.

```
enabled=boolean
         When set to False, xdg-user-dirs-update will
         not change the XDG user dirs configuration.
```